# Search the commit with the same file

Tags: git

I have two repos. 
First of them is a fork of second.
I need move some changes from one repo to another.

So cherry-pick looks like a good idea.

After:

```
git add remote A <path to second repo> 
git fetch A
```

I got one repo with complicated history and branches structure.
I can use cherry-pick now. But i need to find point of difference.

Actually I can use something like this:

```
git diff HEAD:/some/file/with/changes <SHA>:/some/file/with/changes
```

to see difference between one file in different commit. In this way I can try to find location without difference in this file (using different SHA). But it takes a lot of time.

Can git do it automatically?
So the main question: how find commit in different branches with the same file in Git repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git diff master..fork FILENAME` to see the changes in the file called `FILENAME` between the branches.

If you need to see all the commits that changed the file, use `git log --follow FILENAME`